# SQL Join multiple tables with the same column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm guessing this is very simple but I'm totally new to this.
Could you please help to join these 3 or more tables with the same column name into one large table. Examples given below. I have table 2017 to 2019 and the resultant image at the bottom is what I am trying to get.

What is the SQL BigQuery code for this? Thanks!

[image: Table_2017]

[image: Table_2018]
[image: Table_2019]

--------WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE ---------------

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want `union all`:

```
select t.*
from table_2017 t
union all
select t.*
from table_2018 t
union all
select t.*
from table_2019 t;
```

The use of `t.*` is a convenience, assuming the tables have the same names, in the same order with compatible types.  I recommend listing the columns explicitly.

Note:  You should probably fix your data model.  Having multiple tables with the same columns is not a good data model.  All this data should be in one table.

Comment: @ryanlewis . . . If this answers your question, you can accept the ansewr.

Comment: Trying to find how to accept the answer, sorry im new. How to I accept the answer?