# Python: How to efficiently fetch the latest record from multiple tables in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

Let me give you some background.

The earlier version of the Python script was fetching data from an API after every second and then will create MySQL tables on the fly based on the value of a JSON field returns from API and then insert data into it. I was returning the list of tuples of the API data in this format:

```
[('Name1',9.0),('Name2',1.0)]
```

Then a routine creates table at runtime based on `Name1` and `Name2` text and then eventually `INSERT`s the list of records in the respective tables. In the above case, there will be two tables; `Name1` and `Name2` with the following row each:

- Name1,9.0
- Name2,1.0

Now the data ingestion part has been separated so instead of having the latest record from API on each second I would have to query these tables and fetch the latest record from each table, in the above example two records should return; one from each table.

Having said all that, what is the efficient way to return the latest records from all(*in the current example above, both tables*) efficiently? By efficient means, I want to avoid multiple requests to the server. If I sent a query like the below which returns two resultsets, is it efficient or there's some other way for better performance and reduce latency?

```
SELECT * FROM `Name1` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;SELECT * FROM `Name2` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Update**

I was told this question is a duplicate of an [existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291328/sql-join-multiple-tables-with-the-same-column-names). I had seen and tried this and it does not solve my problem.

The attached question returns ALL the records from unified tables. All I need is the latest records of each table. I tried the following(*Thanks to ChatGPT*) and it does work

```
Explain SELECT * FROM `Name1`
UNION 
SELECT * FROM `Name2`

ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

The LIMIT is 2 here because there are two tables in this example but in reality, they could be 30+ at any instant.

So the question remains: Is this the right way and is it efficient, especially when two different scripts pull and store records each second?

**Update**

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Other tables (e,g: mytable1...mytableN) will have identical schema
Thanks

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and indicate what column indicates "latest".  Do you want 1 row from each table?  Or the later of the two?  Can there be dups?

Comment: @RickJames Just done. the `id` column. Yes one row (the latest one). Yes prices could be duplicates across tables

Comment: I'm getting lost.  If there is only one `mytable`, then I would expect `FROM my_table WHERE name = "name1"`.

Comment: @RickJames Sorry I was not clear, there are multiple tables `mytable` , `mytable1` with identical schema

Comment: Red flag!  Having multiple tables with identical schema is _usually_ a mistake -- it makes queries clumsy to write and slow to run.  What distinguishes the tables?  "Name1" versus "Name2"?  Let's start by folding the tables into a single table -- with an extra column to distinguish them.